# Run a (single) program as root

Tags: permissions, root

I have been given a tool that uses a closed source library to operate the hardware watchdog timer on my "PC".  The library insists on being run as root.

I have tried modifying the sudoers file to allow admin to run the program with NOPASSWORD set and I tried this also with  a new group.  I also tried making the permission of the file rwsw-x--.  None of these worked or I just did them wrong.  So,

How can I mark a program to allow a simple user (i.e. my userid) to run with root privileges?  TNX.

Comment: What about `sudo proram_name`? That's the way programs are run as root in Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, without some machinations, sudo requires a password which I don't want to have to supply or use.  It an embedded system and the app tickles a watchdog.  Shouldn't have to be root but some dimkwit decided to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setuid command to make it so *anyone* running the binary is root. Keep in mind this is a massive security hole, if the binary is compromised then they have root access to your PC.

For the most part setuid is evil. Does *sudo /path/to/bin* really not work?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in replying.  Yes, sudo path-ro-bin does work.  I just didn't catch the required-ness of "sudo".  Thanks for your help!